# How to handle the situation in apex when retrieving the data

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to handle the situation in apex when retrieving data from object with condition and no rows will return?

```
if (list.size() > 0){
    //some code
}
else{
    //other code
}
```

but it shows error like

**Visualforce Remoting Exception: List index out of bounds: 0**

Comment: Can you please post the actual code where this error is occurring and point out the line?

Comment: Are you getting this error from the posted code? Looks like you are having a `JavaScript` issue in `RemoteAction` method. Post any remote action scripts if you are using

Comment: It would be great if you can paste some code here.

Comment: list<_Service_Property__c> lstClinicalProperty = [Select Id,Property_Value__c,Property_Value2__c from Service_Property__c where Service__c = :clinicId and Property_Type__c = 'ClinicalTime'];
       DateTime today = System.now();
       if(lstClinicalProperty.size() > 0 ){} else{}

Comment: I would like to handle the above situation

Comment: @RamKosal, if you are using JavaScript remoting can you edit your question and add that as well?

Answer (score 0):

About your question,

In apex you could use `isEmpty` or `size` methods to know when a list has elements:

In your sample code it would be:

```
list<Service_Property__c> lstClinicalProperty = [Select Id,Property_Value__c,Property_Value2__c from Service_Property__c where Service__c = :clinicId and Property_Type__c = 'ClinicalTime'];

if(!lstClinicalProperty.isEmpty() ){
 //some code
} else{
 //other
}
```

Regarding the error, I think that your code is ok, but probably you are trying to access a list element in other line. Paste the entire code if you can't find it.

For more info read [isEmpty](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/Chunk1715647141.htm#apex_System_List_isEmpty) official doc.

Note: I've noticed that you have a little typo when you are defining the list, one extra underscore **_Service_Property__c**

Comment: I does not works! Martin Borthiry

Comment: this is only the code

Comment: as I commented I think that you have an error in other code not posted. Are you using remote actions?

Comment: yes I use remote action

Comment: The error was cleared,code saved successfully but when call it using remote action it shows the error like above

Comment: the theme is if the record is not available in the object means I should create a new one

Comment: paste your complete code, remote call and if clause code also

Comment: code is too long i cant paste it here